# Develop in/ according to [some] scenario

Tags: prepositions

Please fill the blank:

> If the measures are not taken, the situation may develop ___ the worst scenario.

'According to'? 'In'? I would like to avoid rephrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scenario) defines **scenario** as

> a description of possible actions or events in the future

If you really had a description of a situation, and you were expecting actual events to follow this description, "**according to** [the description]" would probably be the best option.

The idiomatic expression **worst case scenario** is defined as

> the most unpleasant or serious thing that could happen in a situation

Note that, unlike **scenario** on its own, this idiom is used about **what could happen** rather than **a description of what could happen**: as such, **according to** is not  appropriate.

Generally we use the preposition [**into**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/into) rather than **in** when something is changing, so if you intend to use the idiom correctly, **into** is the most appropriate.

> If the measures are not taken, the situation may develop into the worst [case] scenario.

Paradoxically, we usually consider the possiblility of multiple **worst case scenarios**, and use **a** rather than **the**, unless we intend to go on to define what we consider to be **the** worst case scenario, for example:

> The worst case scenario from the defendants' perspective would have been that they erroneously turned Smart over to the Sheriff in the belief that they were required to do so by the 1958 order. - *Smart V. Simonson, United States Court of Appeals for the Seventh Circuit, 1988*

You might, therefore, wish to consider using **a worst** rather than **the worst**

Answer (score 1):

If the *scenario* you're talking about is a projection of how things could develop, then *according to* works fine - it would mean that things are following the course of events imagined in that scenario. Because it has that sense of *following* something, this makes more sense for a projection based on an understanding of cause and effect, not random outcomes (which you couldn't really *follow*).

*Develop into* works fine too, this is more of a sense of things changing from one situation to another. There isn't the same feeling of following a projected sequence of events here, the *scenario* is more of a description of how things will end up in a more general sense.

*Develop in the worst scenario* **sort of** works, but I feel like it's looking at things in a different way. If you're *in* a particular scenario (if that scenario is playing out in reality) then you can say "this is how things will develop". So being in that scenario is what causes the developments, not the other way around. It's a subtle difference.